# dict(sorted(dictionary.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)) does not always return a ordered dict when the value is a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a dict:

```
count2:defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'i': [3, 2, 2, 1], 'w': [2, 2], 'p': [2, 2], 'd': [2, 2], 'm': [2, 2], 'y': [2, 2, 2, 1], 'x': [2, 2, 4, 1], 'j': [2, 2], 'o': [2, 1], 'r': [2, 1]})
```

when I try to sort it by using

```
ordered = dict(sorted(count2.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True))
```

It not always sorts it like I want it to sort. (the value must have the biggest number and then descend) so it returns this:

```
orderedStart:{'i': [3, 2, 2, 1], 'x': [2, 2, 4, 1], 'y': [2, 2, 2, 1], 'w': [2, 2], 'p': [2, 2], 'd': [2, 2], 'm': [2, 2], 'j': [2, 2], 'o': [2, 1], 'r': [2, 1]}
```

everything is right except for that `x` should be in front of `i` since `4 > 3`.
Are some indexes more prioritized?

To facilitate the users , here is an Example of a well sorted list using the same code.

Before:

```
count2:defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'r': [2, 2, 2, 1], 'g': [2, 1], 'e': [3, 1], 'n': [5, 1], 't': [4, 1], 'i': [2, 1], 'o': [5, 1], 'm': [2, 1]})
```

After:

```
{'n': [5, 1], 'o': [5, 1], 't': [4, 1], 'e': [3, 1], 'r': [2, 2, 2, 1], 'g': [2, 1], 'i': [2, 1], 'm': [2, 1]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you compare lists, they're compared lexicographically, so the first element takes precedence, then the second, and so on. If you want the largest list element to take precedence, compare sorted lists.

```
ordered = dict(sorted(count2.items(), key=lambda item: sorted(item[1], reverse=True), reverse=True))
```

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand how python compares tuples.  You have asked it to compare `[3, 2, 2, 1]` and `[2, 2, 4, 1]`.  Since 3 > 2, it comes first.

Python uses "lexicographic comparison", which is identical to the way you look up words in a dictionary.  First you compare the first letters.  If they are different, you're done; if they are different, you look at the second letter.  And so forth.

Comment: There must be many duplicates of this, but I can't find them. "compare lists" finds questions about comparing list elements, and "order lists" finds questions about sorting the contents of lists.

Comment: @Barmar I cannot find them either. If I would've found them this question probably wouldn't exist.

Comment: @Frank Yellin , isn't there a way too look up two numbers at the same time and only compare the max result

Comment: @Pipassinsal You could sort the lists in descending order and compare those.